# Uploading image file from React native to ASP.net core API

Tags: android, react-native, asp.net-core, axios

I'm trying to upload image from React native(without expo) (on Android OS only) to a post endpoint in ASP.net core web API.
In my react native app, I have used 'react-native-image-picker' to capture the image using camera like below.

```
launchCamera(options, (response: ImagePickerResponse) => {
      console.log('Response = ', response);

      
      if (response.assets) {
        setVehicle({
          ...vehicle,
          image: {
            name: response.assets[0].fileName,
            uri: response.assets[0].uri,
            type: response.assets[0].type,
          },
        });
      }
    });
```

Once I have the image details is my vehicle state, I'm adding it to form data and doing axios post call like below.

```
const data = new FormData();
data.append('image', {
  name: vehicle.image.name,
  uri: vehicle.image.uri,
  type: vehicle.image.type,
});
axios.post('https://localhost:44343/api/vehicle', data, {
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
    },
  });
```

My post endpoint in ASP.net core web api looks like this.

```
    [Route("")]
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Post([FromForm(Name = "image")]IFormFile image)
    {
        //Upload the image to blob storage
    }
```

The image argument variable always contains null value in this endpoint, I tried many think but couldn't fix this. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Finally found a way to upload images. Not sure if this is the ideal way, but this the only way I could make it work.

After getting the image URI of captured image, I fetched the blob for the image.

```
const image = await fetch(vehicleImageURI);
const blob = await image.blob();
const fileReaderInstance = new FileReader();
fileReaderInstance.readAsDataURL(blob);
fileReaderInstance.onload = () => {
  const base64data = fileReaderInstance.result;
  postVehicle({ ...vehicle, base64Image: base64data as string })
    .then((res) => {
      console.log(res);
    })
    .catch((ex) => {
      console.log(ex);
    });
};
```

On the API side I removed the IFormFile and FromForm from post endpoint and removed the base64image as string.

```
[Route("")]
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Post(string image)
{
    Regex regex = new Regex(@"^[\w/\:.-]+;base64,");
    var base64File = regex.Replace(data.Base64Image, string.Empty);
    byte[] imageBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(base64File);
    MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.Length);
}
```

Please let us known if you know a better way to do this!