# Saving Image to API via FormData from React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native, image, blob, multipartform-data

I am developing an expo app and need to be able to save a picture as part of a larger post request.
I am sending the request using a FormData object on the frontend, so that the images can be parsed as IFormFile objects on the backend. I am sending the request as multipart/form-data.

On the frontend, the image is taken from the device's camera using a camera component, and the image uri is stored in an array to be sent/processed when the API call is made. I am using a fetch call to take the image URI and convert it to a blob, which can then be used to create an array of bytes. When I log the byteArray length, it appears that an array has been created. I have found that passing a File object is the only way the API recognizes that something has been sent in the 'Photos' field.

When I run the API in debug mode, I expect 'Photos' to contain an IFormFile object that has a byte length >0 that gets saved in the Images folder. Instead, the IFormFile object is 0 bytes long and the image that appears in the images folder is corrupted.

The API processes the request successfully and returns a 200, and all data is read correctly from the form, except the image, though it does not throw an error. When I upload an image through swagger, it saves correctly and the image appears in the Images folder in the API.

I believe the issue is with how I am processing the image URI into the File object.

```
const formData = new FormData();

let response = await fetch(uri);

const blob = await response.blob();
const buffer = await new Response(blob).arrayBuffer();          
const byteArray = new Uint8Array(buffer);
            
if (byteArray.length > 0) console.log(byteArray.length) //this prints a length of ~6,000,000

const file = new File([byteArray], "example.jpg", { type: "image/jpg", });

formData.append('otherStringData', string) //the form takes a number of other pieces of data, which are successfully read by the API
formData.append('photos', file)

return formData; //this is passed to a component that sends the form data in a react query useMutation
```

Comment: Update: I never found a solution using FormData but [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71979163/uploading-image-file-from-react-native-to-asp-net-core-api) has a solution using Base64 data that I ended up using